# List manipulation related

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists `l1={a,b,c}` and `l2={{a1},{b1,b2},{c1,c2,c3}}`.
What kind of operations can I use to get a list like
`l={{a,a1},{b,b1},{b,b2},{c,c1},{c,c2},{c,c3}}`?

I tried to use `Thread` to get around, but I failed.
Any suggestions?

**Update**: I also have a function `f`, in the end I want to arrive at something like 
`f@@@l={f[a, a1], f[b, b1], f[b, b2], f[c, c1], f[c, c2], f[c, c3]}`.
I can do that with `Table` as follows:

```
Flatten@Table[f[l1[[i]], #] & /@ l2[[i]], {i, Length@l1}]
```

But I wonder whether there are other ways.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the link. What am I supposed to do with my post then? Shall I close it or delete it?

Comment: Posts closed as a duplicate are left here as a road sign for future visitors. And since it's not easy to find such duplicates, that is desired. :)(so do not delete it please :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first request:

```
Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{l1, l2}], 1]
```

For the second request, you just need `Listable`:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
Flatten@f[l1, l2]
```

OK, actually the first request can also be satisfied by setting `Listable` attribute:

```
g = Function[{a, b}, {a, b}, Listable]
Flatten[g[l1, l2], 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ways you could use `Thread` to achieve your goal:

```
l1 = {a, b, c} ;
l2 = {{a1}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2, c3}};
Join @@ (Thread[{#1, #2}] & @@@ Thread[{l1, l2}])
Join @@ MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {l1, l2}]
Inner[Sequence @@ Thread[{#1, #2}] &, l1, l2, List]
```