# Creating a list with Thread

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I have a list like this one:

```
aaah= {{11, 21, 31}, {12, 22, 32}, {13, 23, 33}}
```

and I finally want to get a list which looks like this one:

```
{{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, 
 {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, 
 {{3, 13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}
```

I am pretty sure that I can use `Thread`, `List` and `Range` to do this, but I can't get the right combination...

At the moment this is my best try:

```
Thread[List[Table[1, 3], aaah[[1]]]]
```

which does exactly what I want, but only on the first row.
I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99567/1871

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is with `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[
  {#2[[1]], #1} &,
  aaah,
  {2}
]
```

> {{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, {{3, 13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}

Comment: An equivalent method: `MapIndexed[ReplacePart[#2, 2 -> #1] &, {{11, 21, 31}, {12, 22, 32}, {13, 23, 33}}, {2}]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
MapIndexed[Thread @ {First @ #2, #} &] @ aaah
```

> ```
> {{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}},
> {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, 
> {{3, 13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread/@Transpose[{Range[3],aaah}]
```

> {{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, {{3, 13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}

Or:

```
aaah//Thread/@Transpose[{Range@Length@#,#}]&
```

Or:

```
aaah//MapThread[Thread@*List,{Range@Length@#,#}]&
```

Answer (score 5):

```
idxs = Range[3]
Thread /@ Thread[{idxs, aaah}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun. Another options using `Distribute`:

```
MapIndexed[Distribute[{#2, #}, List] &]@aaah
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the most natural way of doing this is by using `MapIndexed`. But if you want to use `Range` and `Thread`, this is one way:

```
{{11, 21, 31}, {12, 22, 32}, {13, 23, 33}} //
  {Length /* Range, Identity} //
  Through //
  Thread //
  Map[Thread]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Thread, Range, Length, and Tranpose:

`Thread[{Range[1, Length[aaah]], #}] & /@ Transpose[aaah] // Transpose`

Answer (score 2):

Three more possibilities:

```
list = {{11, 21, 31}, {12, 22, 32}, {13, 23, 33}};

MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {Range @ Length @ list, list}]
```

{{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, {{3,
13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}

```
Module[{i = 1}, Thread[{i++, #}] & /@ list]
```

{{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, {{3,
13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}

```
ReplacePart[list, i_ :> Thread[{i, list[[i]]}]]
```

{{{1, 11}, {1, 21}, {1, 31}}, {{2, 12}, {2, 22}, {2, 32}}, {{3,
13}, {3, 23}, {3, 33}}}